# Swift mimic animated: animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am using `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)`

I wonder where I can see how that animation is built in code?
I want to mimic its behavior with another custom UIView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is just a slide up, so an animation is created that changes the y-origin of the view being animated.

If using auto layout, you should have a top constraint that specifies that the view's top y position is equal to the superview's top y position. You can reference these `NSLayoutConstraint`s using `@IBOutlet` like you can with other storyboard elements, so in your view controller:

```
class MyViewController {
    @IBOutlet var viewToAnimate: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

You will notice that `NSLayoutConstraint` has a `constant` property, which just specifies a value to add to the second constraint attribute when calculating the resulting layout frames using that constraint. So in the case of the `topConstraint`, you want to add `-viewToAnimate.bounds.height`*, so that the bottom of the view sits just out of sight at the top of the superview.

You animate changes using the `UIView` class method `animateWithDuration(_:animations:)` - any animatable `UIView` properties that are changed inside the `animation` closure will be animated over the specified `duration`. But when you change your constraint's `constant` property, the view properties aren't changed until another layout pass is performed on the view. You can invalidate the layout, and let the layout happen in the next pass implicitly with `view.setNeedsLayout()`, but we need the layout pass to happen *inside* the view's animation block for the animation to work. So instead, you can use `layoutIfNeeded()` to force the subviews to layout immediately.

Put together, your animate method might look something like this:

```
class MyViewController {

    // ...

    func animateViewUp() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
            self.topConstraint.constant = -self.viewToAnimate.bounds.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }        
}
```

In reality, you would likely specify a method that allows you to toggle between a shown/hidden state, but the above code should get you started.

**N.B. Check which way around the constraint is specified! If the constraint is specified in terms of your superview, then a negative `constant` will move the subview downwards!*

Comment: Thanks Stuart I got it working perfectly. But I ran into another problem. After the animation, if I keep going to another VC then go back again to VC1, the UIView will still be hidden. Is there any way to make it visible before going back?

Comment: I tried to reset it in viewDidAppear() It works but you can clearly see it jump down again which looks bad

Comment: @user2722667 You probably want to try `viewWillAppear(_:)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't. The source for Apple's frameworks is not provided. However, most of their animations are built on top of the same Core Animation framework that us third party developers use.

What is the effect this creates? I'm not sure I've ever animated away the navigation bar on a view controller that's in place. Can you post a GIF of the animation? I can probably give you an idea of how it's done if I know what it looks like.

Comment: I will post a gif, on my phone right now. But its a simple slideUp animation, about 0.5 in duration.

Comment: Ok, a slide up animation is trivial to do using UIView animation methods in the family `animateWithDuration`. If you're using AutoLayout then you add a vertical position constraint, connect it to an outlet, then change it's constant value and call layoutIfNeeded in the animation block.